# XPath Select Parent and Multiple Children

Tags: xpath

In Xpath how would I get my results to select all documents and display them like

```
        <Document>
         <Size>100</Size>
         <Offset>200</Offset>
         <FileName>x.doc</FileName>
        </Document>
```

from

```
 <Documents>
    <Document>
         <Size>100</Size>
         <Offset>200</Offset>
         <FileName>x.doc</FileName>
         <Details>
             <Header>asdfasdf</Header>
             <Footer>adfasdfas</Footer>
             <Author>asdfasdfs</Author>
             <Date>20140101</Date>
         </Details>
    <Document>
</Documents>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which XPath version? I doubt that is possible with 1.0 (maybe with 3.0), but XPath isn't really intended for such a use case. You are better of using XSLT or XQuery Update.

Comment: It would be Xpath 2.0

Comment: I agree, this is something that should be done with XSLT, not XPath. XPath is a query language, not a transformation language.

Answer (score 0):

With XSLT you get the result with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="//Documents//*">
 <xsl:if test="local-name(parent::*)!='Details' and local-name(.) != 'Details'">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So you would get a copy of all Documents excluding the Details.

Comment: This seems to give me the same result as //Documents/Document/*[self::Offset or self::Size or self::FileName], I want to keep the division between the records.

Comment: @JSmithJ Just adjusted the XSLT, not quite sure if it'll meet your requirements.